# Diameter of a simple graph $G$ and the eigen values of adjacency matrix $A(G)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

> > The diameter of a graph $G$ is less than the number of distinct
> >     eigenvalues of $G$.

If diam$(G) = k$, it is enough to show that $A^0, A, \cdots, A^k$ is linearly  independent, where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$.

Choose $v_i, v_j \in V(G)$ such that $d(v_i, v_j) = k$. Then how to prove that $(i,j)$th entery of $A^k$ is not zero and $(i,j)$th entery of $A^t$ is zero if $t < k$.

> > Is it true that $(i,j)$th entery of $A^s$ is nonzero iff $G$ has a path between $v_i$ and $v_j$ of length $s$.

Answer (score 1):

The $(i,j)$-th entry of $A^k$ is the # of paths that go from $v_i$ to $v_j$ with length $k$. If $d(v_i, v_j) = k$, there exists at least a path from $v_i$ to $v_j$ and therefore, $A^k(i, j) > 0$. Since $t < k$, there does not exist a path from $v_i$ to $v_j$ and therefore $A^t(i, j) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. How to prove this result.

Comment: @user120386 It is helpful to first prove the case for $A^2$. Are you able to prove it by yourself please?

Comment: I can prove for $A^2$. Further i have tried by induction .

Comment: @user120386 Then you should be able to prove that "the $(i,j)$-th entry of $A^k$ is the \# of paths that go from $v_i$ to $v_j$ with length $k$".

Comment: I will try this

Comment: @PSPACEhard Isn't the (i,j)-the entry of $A^k$ gives the number of walks that go from $v_i$ to $v_j$ of length $k$? How do you know that it counts the number of paths?